# Residues of a cubic expression

Tags: residue-calculus, cubics

I am trying to find the residues of the expression:
$$f(z) = \frac{e^{z*t}(z^2-2)}{z^3-a\,z^2-2a}$$
but I don't reallly know how to do it, so far I've tried to use partial fractions and also find the roots of the denominator:

$\left\{\left\{z\to \frac{1}{3} \left(\sqrt[3]{a^3+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2 a ^4+27 a^2}+27 a }+\frac{a^2}{\sqrt[3]{a ^3+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2 a^4+27 a^2}+27 a }}+a \right)\right\},\left\{z\to -\frac{1}{6} \left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{a ^3+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2 a ^4+27 a ^2}+27a }-\frac{\left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) a^2}{6 \sqrt[3]{a^3+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2 a^4+27 a^2}+27 a }}+\frac{a}{3}\right\},\left\{z\to -\frac{1}{6} \left(1+i \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{\gamma ^3+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2 a^4+27 a^2}+27 a}-\frac{\left(1-i \sqrt{3}\right) a^2}{6 \sqrt[3]{a ^3+3 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2 a^4+27 a^2}+27 a}}+\frac{a}{3}\right\}\right\}$

, but I think I don't really get a usefull result, I am really knew in this kind of things so I don' t rellay know how to preceed, does anyone has a clue?, Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose that this is part of another problem. Am I right? If so, what's that problem? Any condition on $a$?

Comment: It may make things easier to write the denominator as $(z-r_1)(z-r_2)(z-r_3)$, obtain the residues in terms of these roots, then combine them and look for simplification. It may also be useful to note, from your expressions, that two of the roots are complex-conjugate when $a$ is real and the other is positive real.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the main condition is a is real, and actually this $f(z)$ is used to find a inverse laplace transfor, I think it could be usefull use roots to obtain the residues, actually  at the end I am interested in the positive real root. @JoséCarlosSantos